# Best tool for minimalistic-themed graphics?

Tags: tools, minimalistic

Hey I would like to create art in the style of what's kind of modern since 2013 (I guess). Simple shapes, bright gradients and a generally "flat" appearance. What's the best tool for that? I own Photoshop which I could use for vector stuff but I guess there are better tools out there.

I refer to art like the following:
[image]
[image]

EDIT: Before we drift into a highly philosophical discussion about what "best" means: I simply wanna know what would be the most convenient tool to replicate the style of the above pictures.

Comment: Yes, any vector illustration software would be a good bet...Illustrator, Inkscape, Sketch, the list goes on and on...

Comment: What do you mean with "best tool"? best way to work with, best results? But what is "best" for you? Is it best for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I know you aren't looking for a philosophical answer, but more a pragmatic one, here goes.

Since you already have Photoshop, I'm assuming you have an affinity to Adobe products. The best Adobe program that creates simple vector graphics like these is Illustrator. It works well moving back and forth between photoshop for smart objects and such. It also has a lot of similar tools and effects that you will be familiar with.

I'd say go with that.

Comment: Cheers bro, just read myself into it and it quite looks like what I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

I'd also like to add that if you are in the lookout for a software to use anyway, do give a try on sketch 3.

Couple of pluses:

- Vector based
- Exporting in all kinds of resolutions
- Developed for the web era (you can even export css attributes)
- More affordable than Photoshop
- There are as many sources for sketch as there are for psd (already)

Minus:

- You gotta learn it from scratch.

If you feel the desire to invest time and money in an app, make sure to check it out. I recently purchased it and I am learning all the tricks.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I might give it a go but the review are rather controversial, let's see

Comment: You can always use it for the 30day trial. Don't purchase it before you test it :) And there are a load of tutorials online as well.